# Does anyone know of Prolog code for formatted input?

Tags: prolog, formatted-input

I need to read formatted data from files in Prolog, and something much like C-style "freadf"/"sscanf" would be ideal. Prolog's built-in "format" does a fairly good job at outputting formatted data, but I could not find anything remotely appropriate for input. I am currently using SICStus Prolog, but I am willing to port code from SWI-Prolog if necessary. One might argue that this could be done with a combination of get_char/get_byte, but if I can find ready and tested library/predicates, this would save me a fairly amont of time.

Comment: Is there a reason why you like to have a sscanf version over [DCGs](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dgru.html) that are supported in SICSStus Prolog?

Comment: Yes, among other difficulties I will be porting a NLP app to Prolog, and it would take a long time and a heavy debugging effort to adapt tons of sscanf templates to DCGs.

Comment: It is probably easiest to write little pre-reader in C or Perl, which can output Prolog terms to the Prolog process with a pipe.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: This sounds like an effective and efficient method. A potential alternative in Prolog could be the the [tokenize package](https://github.com/shonfeder/tokenize), if your scanf expressions are easy. But If you have tons of expressions, converting them to Prolog is not always fun :-)

Comment: read/1 is a very powerful **formatted** input analyzer. Indeed it's a full Prolog parser, where you can shape expressions with appropriate op/3 directives. So, could be that your task is easier than you think. Please put a sample of what you consider a complex/complete input to read in your question.